# Keycloak federation with LDAP fails to make the connection : Error! Error when trying to connect to LDAP. See server.log for details

Tags: ldap, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am trying to create a federated authentication using the Keycloak and following the steps mentioned here: [Setup User Federation with Keycloak](https://documentation.abas.cloud/en/abas-keycloak/setup-user-federation-ldap.html)

I have been using the port `10389` instead of `389` mentioned in the document. Everything seems to be working fine until the step where I am making the connection from Keycloak to LDAP.

When I provide the `Connection URL` as `ldap://localhost:10389` and click on the `Test Connection` then I get the error:

```
Error! Error when trying to connect to LDAP. See server.log for details
```

I am not sure what's wrong because when I check in the `Apache Directory Studio` there everything seems to be working fine for me and I am able to get all the users list etc. I am not sure why I am unable to make the connection from Keycloak to LDAP.

I tried the following things but nothing worked for me:

1. ldap://localhost:10389
2. localhost:10389
3. ldap://127.0.0.1:10389
4. ldap://localhost:389
5. Stopped the docker in the dashboard and started again.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After trying a lot I found the solution. Posting the answer as it can be useful to someone else in the future.

I was using the `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` which was not working. Finally, I checked the IP Address of my system using the terminal (for mac `ipconfig`) and tried that and it worked:

`ldap://192.168.1.12:10389`

Comment: I'm using containerized "ApacheDS" on "Docker for WSL2". In configuration screen you have to type ip address of the WSL machine.

Comment: I was using a DNS for connecting to my LDAP from KC. Something like ldap://sts-ldap-server:3389, and that dint work.

I got the ip address by pinging to sts-ldap-server, used that and it worked.

Comment: in windows i ran ipconfig in terminal to get the ip address and it worked. by the way in my case i was running openldap inside docker container

Answer (score 1):

For me, I am running Keycloak and OpenLDAP on docker containers. I solved the issue by replacing `ldap://localhost:389` with `ldap://host.docker.internal:389`.